# Using SCons as a build engine for distutils

Tags: python, scons, distutils

I have a python package with some C code needed to build an extension (with some non-trivial building needs). I have used SCons as my build system because it's really good and flexible.

I'm looking for a way to compile my python extensions with SCons ready to be distributed with distutils. I want that the user simply types setup.py install and get the extension compiled with SCons instead of the default distutils build engine.

An idea that comes to mind is to redefine build_ext command in distutils, but I can't find extensive documentation for it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [enscons package](https://bitbucket.org/dholth/enscons) seems to be designed to do what the question asked. An example of using it to build a package with C extensions is [here](https://bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular/src).

You could have a basic package structure like:

```
pkgroot/
    pyproject.toml
    setup.py
    SConstruct
    README.md
    pkgname/
        __init__.py
        pkgname.py
        cfile.c
```

In this the `pyproject.toml` file could look something like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["enscons"]

[tool.enscons]
name = "pkgname"
description = "My nice packahe"
version = "0.0.1"
author = "Me"
author_email = "me@me.com"
keywords = ["spam"]
url = "https://github.com/me/pkgname"
src_root = ""
packages = ["pkgname"]
```

where the `[tool.enscons]` section contains many things familiar to the setuptools/distutils `setup` functions. Copying from [here](https://bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular/src), the `setup.py` function could contain something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Call enscons to emulate setup.py, installing if necessary.

import sys, subprocess, os.path

sys.path[0:0] = ['setup-requires']

try:
    import enscons.setup
except ImportError:
    requires = ["enscons"] 
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 
        "-t", "setup-requires"] + requires)
    del sys.path_importer_cache['setup-requires'] # needed if setup-requires was absent
    import enscons.setup

enscons.setup.setup()
```

Finally, the `SConstruct` file could look something like:

```
# Build pkgname

import sys, os
import pytoml as toml
import enscons, enscons.cpyext

metadata = dict(toml.load(open('pyproject.toml')))['tool']['enscons']

# most specific binary, non-manylinux1 tag should be at the top of this list
import wheel.pep425tags
full_tag = next(tag for tag in wheel.pep425tags.get_supported() if not 'manylinux' in tag)

env = Environment(tools=['default', 'packaging', enscons.generate, enscons.cpyext.generate],
                  PACKAGE_METADATA=metadata,
                  WHEEL_TAG=full_tag)

ext_filename = os.path.join('pkgname', 'libcfile')

extension = env.SharedLibrary(target=ext_filename,
                              source=['pkgname/cfile.c'])

py_source = Glob('pkgname/*.py')

platlib = env.Whl('platlib', py_source + extension, root='')
whl = env.WhlFile(source=platlib)

# Add automatic source files, plus any other needed files.
sdist_source=list(set(FindSourceFiles() + 
    ['PKG-INFO', 'setup.py'] + 
    Glob('pkgname/*', exclude=['pkgname/*.os'])))

sdist = env.SDist(source=sdist_source)
env.Alias('sdist', sdist)

install = env.Command("#DUMMY", whl, 
                      ' '.join([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--no-deps', '$SOURCE']))
env.Alias('install', install)
env.AlwaysBuild(install)

env.Default(whl, sdist)
```

After this you should be able to run

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

to compile the C extension and build a wheel, and install the python package, or

```
python setup.py sdist
```

to build a source distribution.

I think you can basically do anything you could with SCons in the `SConstruct` file though.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I've added a more concrete example derived from the links.

Comment: I think @joeforker is the author of enscons, so they could maybe add to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the page: http://www.scons.org/wiki/PythonExtensions

I'm using slightly modified version to build pyrex-c extensions for python.

Comment: My question is more about doing that (compiling python extension with) in the setup.py script in the cleanest way possible. In this way I can easily distribute my application.

Comment: @pygabriel To compile C extensions you don't need SCons. At all.

Comment: @bialix, It's not about needing scons or not, for example I have a project already using scons for building... How would I plug it in distutils in order to write only "python setup.py install" or develop and distutils would be just calling scons

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix you need to write extension to distutils then. That extension will be the part of your project. TS had the right assumption: "redefine build_ext command". The most complete documentation on build_ext is the sources of build_ext itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use scons to generate a setup.py file.  So I created a template called setup.py.in and use scons to expand the template to generate setup.py.

Here are some links to my project that does this:

[setup.py.in template](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsound/code/756/tree/branch/nsound-dev-weegreenblobbie/setup.py.in)

[The SConstruct](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsound/code/756/tree/branch/nsound-dev-weegreenblobbie/SConstruct)

This computes a dictionary of key, value pairs to substitute into the setup.py.in template to generate setup.py.

So the end user does two things:

```
scons setup.py
python setup.py install
```

Warning: my sconstruct stuff is a bit messy as I wrote it awhile ago, but it should demonstrate the concept.

If you learn how to write proper scons tools, then this can be transformed into a single target, for example:

```
scons --pymod
```

Here is a scons tool the generates a Python wrapper with SWIG:

```
import SCons.Action
from SCons.Script import EnsureSConsVersion

SCons.Script.EnsureSConsVersion(0,96,92)

SwigGenAction = SCons.Action.Action('$SWIGGENCOM', '$SWIGGENCOMSTR')

def emitter(target, source, env):
    """
    Add dependency from target to source
    """

    env.Depends(target, source)

    return target, source


def generate(env):
    """
    Add builders and construction variables for the SwigGen builder.
    """

    if 'SWIGCOM' not in env:
        raise SystemError("SCons build environment could not detect tool: swig")

    bld = env.Builder(
        action = SwigGenAction,
        emitter = emitter,
        target_factory = env.fs.File)

    env['BUILDERS']['SwigGen'] = bld

    env['SWIGGENCOM'] = env['SWIGCOM']


def exists(env):
    return env.Detect('swig')
```

Now from your SConstruct file, you can generate the wrapper code:

```
foobar_cc = env.SwigGen("foobar_wrap.cc", "foobar.i")
```

If you modify foobar.i it will regenerate foobar_wrap.cc.  Once you have this, you can write other tools for actually executing python setup.py install for you, so when --pymod is provided it will build the python module.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to provide custom cmdclass derived from distutils.cmd.Commmand which builds the module how you want it:

```
import distutils.cmd

class build_py_cmd(distutils.cmd.Command):
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        print("Calling SCons to build the module")
        pbs.scons()


setup(name = 'riak3k',
      packages = ['riak3k'],
      package_dir = {'': 'build/release'},
      cmdclass = {'build_py': build_py_cmd},
```

Comment: What is the `pbs` import?

Comment: It looks like the `pbs` module is from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbs, for calling OS functions as python functions.  As far as I can tell, it would be equivalent to `subprocess.check_call(['scons'])`.